# How to read multidimensional array in Verilog using $readmemh?

Tags: arrays, verilog, system-verilog, test-bench

I have a multi-dimensional array:

```
logic [7:0] memory[1:0][1:0];
```

and a comma-separated file.txt:

```
1,2
3,4
```

I am not able to load this file with `$readmemh`:

```
initial
begin
   $readmemh("file.txt", memory);
end
```

Could you suggest a solution?

Comment: As the answer below already deals with what will work, Ill just mention this in a comment; the problem specifically is the commas, `readmem` files can only contain white space, comments, addresses and/or numbers (either binary for `readmemb` or hex for `readmemh`).  So, to separate values, just use spaces and/or new lines. See section 21.4 of the 2012 LRM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
logic [7:0] mem [1:0][1:0]
```

For the above 4 elements array each of 8 bits. Define the mem.dat file as follows

```
01 02
03 04
```

Then read the file in one shot using readmemh

```
initial
begin
   $readmemh("mem.dat", mem);
end
```

Comment: Your example would be even more helpful if both unpacked array ranges were not the same, [3:0][1:0] for example.